# php OOP - related to method visibility

Tags: php, oop

Check below given code. I could not get that how it had called testPrivate() method of Class Bar class. As per my assumption it should call method from Foo class i.e. Foo::testPrivate.

[**Check the demo here**](http://codepad.org/pa2RdBJg)

```
 <?php
    class Bar 
    {
        public function test() {
            $this->testPrivate();
            $this->testPublic();
        }

        public function testPublic() {
            echo "Bar::testPublic\n";
        }

        private function testPrivate() {
            echo "<br>Bar::testPrivate\n";
        }
    }

    class Foo extends Bar 
    {
        public function testPublic() {
            echo "<br>Foo::testPublic\n";
        }

        private function testPrivate() {
            echo "<br>Foo::testPrivate\n";
        }
    }

    $myFoo = new foo();
    $myFoo->test(); // Bar::testPrivate 
                    // Foo::testPublic
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a child class to be able to overload a method defined in a parent class, that method has to be declared as **`protected`** -- and not as **`private`**.

Here, if you change your `testPrivate` methods definitions to :

```
protected function testPrivate() {
    echo "<br>Bar::testPrivate\n";
}
```

and :

```
protected function testPrivate() {
    echo "<br>Foo::testPrivate\n";
}
```

You'll get the output you expected :

```
Foo::testPrivate
Foo::testPublic
```

For more informations, you should take a look at the [**Visibility**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) section of the manual -- quoting the first sentences :

> Class members declared public can be
>   accessed everywhere. 
> Members
>   declared protected can be accessed
>   only within the class itself and by
>   inherited and parent classes.
>   
> Members declared as private may
>   only be accessed by the class that
>   defines the member.

Comment: yes..you are right...but I am not clear for this code. Bar::test() is public. So it will inherited in Foo class. So now when it will be called from Foo object it should called private mathod of foo class that is Foo::testPrivate.

Comment: Except your `Bar::test()` method is not overloaded in the `Foo` class : it is in the `Bar` class -- and, as your `testPrivate` method is private... ;; if you overload the `test()` method in the `Foo` class, and `testPrivate` remains private, it's `Foo::private` that will get called.

Comment: that is what i am thinking. that it should call Foo::testPrivate not Bar::testPrivate. But when we execute code it is calling Bar::testPrivate. That is y I am confuse. This code is from visibility->Method Visibility section in OOP php maual.

Comment: `testPrivate` is private ; so `Foo::testPrivate` is only visible from inside `Foo` ; and `Bar::testPrivate` is only visible from inside `Bar` ;; `Bar::test` is in `Bar` ; so `Bar::test` only sees `Bar::testPrivate`, and doesn't see `Foo::testPrivate` -- that's how `private` works ; and that's the difference between `private` and `protected`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what a *private* method is.  Foo::testPrivate() can only be call from inside Foo itself. You can acheive the behaviour you describe with a *protected* method. Protected means visible to the class and any classes which extend it.

Comment: yes...but Bar::test() is all ready inherited to Foo. So it is in side Foo only and can call Foo::testPrivate() ...correct me if i am wrong

Comment: No, test() still belongs to Bar. From the outside it's callable as a method on a Foo object, but inside it's still a private Bar method.